# Uncaught Error: Material UI: makeStyles is not longer exported from @mui/material/styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui

**makeStyles is not longer exported from @mui/material/styles.**

Even I am importing from `@mui/styles` all over in my project but still it is showing this error.
I removed `node_modules` and reinstalled but not working

[image]

Comment: Code snippet `https://stackoverflow.com/a/69457917/6207266`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

makeStyles is not longer exported from @mui/material/styles. It is now export from @mui/styles.

Here:

Install: `npm install @mui/styles`

Then Import: `import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';`

I hope it mix your problem but if not please tell me in the comment.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: Can't install @mui/styles with React 18. Any other recomendation?

Answer (score 4):

Install This :

> npm install @mui/styles --legacy-peer-deps

Import This :

> import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue (with withStyles instead) after I thought I replaced all the imports correctly. Turns out there were still things imported like...

```
import { withStyles, TableCell, TableBody } from '@mui/material';
```

So just make sure to search for "withStyles," and/or "withStyles }" in your code editor and ensure you have updated all the imports for withStyles correctly like...

```
import { withStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```